# How to edit Column in Command in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have one issue, there is one column in Command who's length is restricted to 255 characters, so if there is more data than 255 characters to display then it is getting truncated, I need to know how do I increase the length/size of column which is created in Command section in Crystal report ?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a column from the underlying database, then use Verify Database option in crystal report to reflect the changes in the report. If you are using a variable or temp table in the command object it will be taken care automatically. You can verify the size of the column from the context menu shown below which can be brought up by right clicking on the Command in the Field explorer

[image]